# How can I solve this type mismatch in Scala?

Tags: scala

```
 def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    if (chars.isEmpty == true) true
       else transCount(chars, 0)

 def transCount(chars: List[Char], pro: Int): Boolean = {
  var dif = pro
  chars match {
    case "(" :: Nil => false
    case ")" :: Nil => dif -= 1; if (dif == 0) true else false
    case _ :: Nil => if (dif == 0) true else false

    case "(" :: tail => dif += 1
      transCount(tail, dif)
    case ")" :: tail => dif -= 1;
      if (dif < 0) false
      else transCount(tail, dif)
    case _ :: tail => transCount(tail, dif)
    }
  }
}
```

I have the type mismatch problem

```
Error:(30, 13) type mismatch;
 found   : String("(")
 required: Char
       case "(" :: Nil => false
            ^
```

but really do not know how to fix (do not use `char.toList` please)

Comment: `Char` literals use single quotes so you need to use `case '(' :: Nil => false ... ` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chars` is declared as a `List[Char]`.

However, your first pattern is `"(" :: Nil`, which is a `List[String]` because `"("` is a String - hence the type mismatch.

You need a character literal `'('`, not a String literal `"("`

The same applies to the other patterns, of course.